# How can I make the vue-router change when changing parameters? (vuex)

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I'm making an app that has advanced search api.

[image: example]

You can choose what to look for and how to sort the results. The problem is that the page (vue-router) is updated only when the request changes, but it also should be updated when you change the search terms

How i can do this? I don't even have any ideas.

There is my code that is responsible for requesting the API and updating the router when the request is updated

```js
export default {
    name: "Search",
    data: function () {
        return {
            selectedTag: 'story',
            selectedBy: '',
        };
    },
    components: {
        'Item': Item
    },
    mounted() {
        this.items = this.getItems(this.id)
    },
    beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
        this.items = this.getItems(to.params.id);
        next();
    },
    methods: {
        getItems(id) {
            this.items = this.$store.dispatch('FETCH_SEARCH_RESULTS', {id, tag: this.selectedTag, by: this.selectedBy});
            return this.items;
        },
    },
    created: function () {
        this.getItems(this.$route.params.id);
    },
    computed: {
        items: {
            get() {
                return this.$store.state.searchResults;
            },
            set(value) {
                this.$store.commit("APPEND_SEARCH_RESULTS", value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue.js - update router view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60057473/vue-js-update-router-view)

Comment: How did you map your Search component to your route(s)?