# Reset vue component context on load when different routes use same component

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

Using vue router, I have two routes that are mapped to the same component, and given one route i am passing in a prop as a differentiator, then conditionally rendering content based on that prop. like so.

```
export default {
    path: '/advanced-search',
    name: 'Advanced Search',
    component: AdvancedSearch
}
```

and

```
export default {
    path: '/create-vendor-search',
    name: 'Create Vendor Search',
    component: AdvancedSearch,
    props: { createMode: true }
}
```

These exist in two different files, `advanced-search.route.js` and `createNewVendorSearh.route.js`, respectively. The problem is that both pages are linked in my nav bar, and when i go directly from one to the other, the local state and vuex state of the components don't reset. I need this to be a brand new instance of this component every time a route calls it. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue.js - update router view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60057473/vue-js-update-router-view)

Comment: This is not an ideal situation, because I'm not using a `router-view` in each component. I'm sing it once and don't want to have to pass in a unique key every single time.

Comment: Of course, that's the way `router-view` is typically used.  You don't have to pass anything, that key uses an existing instance property of every component that is already automatically calculated.

Comment: What you describe is the expected behaviour of Vuex: the (global) state should not change depending on the active. Based on the `createMode` name, I maybe see two hints: 1) some data must be in the local state instead of global state. In this case, data can be initialized along with the component. 2) lifecycle hooks: use `created()` or `mounted()` to set up the component correctly

Comment: If anyone stumbles across this later -- what I did was make an init() method that reset all my data manually, and call it on the Created life cycle hook, and also put a watcher on createMode, and called that init method when createMode changes.