# Dynamically show components according to route Vue.JS (v-show works but v-if does not)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

So i need to conditionally render the header and footer based on the top level route. The following code works with v-show in statHeader and footerApp components but this is not what i want as v-show only hides the components using CSS.
v-if actually removes it from the DOM, but it only works once.
It doesnt update when the route changes.
From HOME to ADMIN : v-if hides the header and footer
but coming back to HOME: the header and footer still remains hidden and doesn't update.

New to Vue, help and insight understanding this concept would be very appreciated. Thank You.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <!-- header -->
    <statHeader v-show="checkComponent"/>
    <!-- header -->
    <!-- main content -->
    <div id="content-scroll">
      <router-view/>
    <!-- footer -->
    <footerApp v-show="checkComponent"/>
    <!-- footer -->
    </div>
    <!-- main content -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import footerApp from '@/components/Footer.vue'
import statHeader from '@/components/Header.vue'

export default {
  name:"App",
  data(){
    return{
      viewsList:['admin',],
    }
  },
  components:{
    statHeader,footerApp,
  },
  computed:{
    checkComponent(){
      if(this.$route.matched.some(({ name }) => this.viewsList.includes(name))){
        return false;
      }
      else{
        return true;
      }
    },      
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: I am not sure if this the best way of doing it, but if you use [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/), it has [beforeRouteEnter](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) hook. In this hook you add a class to your footer and header. Refer that class in CSS and set display:none (as you don't want them in DOM). Remove this class in [beforeRouteLeave](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) hook to make them visible again.

Comment: v-show does exactly this. it sets display:none to the element. i want to remove the elements from the HTML. not just hide it

Comment: thanks for the info about the hook though. that might be a better approach than v-show for hiding elements through css

Comment: Does this answer your queston?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60058175/2185093

Comment: nope Dan. that didnt help

Comment: So you're not using the same component in your admin and home route then?  (You didn't show your routes, always a good idea on a route question.)  If not, then there's simply not a reproducible error here.