# Is there a (standard) way that vue router-link can refresh the SAME route with a different key or data?

Tags: vue.js

Note that I'm *not* asking for a work-around, as [a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60057473/vue-js-update-router-view) addresses that topic, and using its solution did not fix the issue for me and ended up resulting in other unwanted behavior.  I've settled on my own workaround (refresh the Vuex store's underlying data that the route depends on), which seems to be the best one from a long-term maintenance perspective.  But I'm asking if I'm missing some 'standard' approach, because this seems like a very common use case from a user perspective - same route, different key or data.

I encountered this on a recent project.

The problem was encountered with:

1. A view
2. A top nav component on that view

The view is called "BlogEntry" and it displays a blog directly after the user creates it.

In addition, there is another blog example in my top-nav that is an 'example' of a good blog.

I'm using a Vue router-link to try and navigate there, but router-link *will not refresh the route* with this separate blog entry ID, even though it successfully updates the URL in the browser.

Here's what the router-link looks like:

```
    <router-link
        :to="{
        name: 'BlogEntry',
        params: { blogId: blogIDField},
        }"
    >
    Good Example: {{ blogIDField }}
    </router-link>
```

**Problem Behavior:** After the user creates their own first blog, they are shown the blog entry at the "BlogEntry" route.  In the top navigation, I also have the above router-link, but since it links to the SAME route, *it refuses to refresh the current route*.

**My Current Solution:** I tried different workarounds, and eventually solved it by creating a *custom button that will refresh the store* and hence, the current route, but I find this ... unsatisfying.

While I understand the need to prevent actual browser refreshes in an SPA app like I've built with Vue, the Vue router-link *should* then be able to duplicate what I can do with a traditional page refresh, right?

Am I missing a option where router-link can refresh its CURRENT route with a new key field?

OTHER RELEVANT CODE:

Router file (index.js):

```
      {
        path: "/blogs/:blogId",
        name: "BlogEntry",
        component: () =>
          import(
            /* webpackChunkName: "blogentry" */         "../views/BlogEntry.vue"
          ),
        beforeEnter(routeTo, routeFrom, next) {
          store
            .dispatch("fetchIndividualBlog", routeTo.params.blogId)
            .then(() => {
              next();
            })
            .catch(() => {
              next({ name: "BlogNotFound" });
            });
        },
      }
```

App.vue:

```
    <template>
      <div id="app">
        <TopNav></TopNav>
        <router-view />
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    import TopNav from "@/components/TopNav.vue";
    export default {
      components: {
        TopNav,
      },
    };
    </script>
```

View (BlogEntry.vue):

```
    <template>
      <div>
        <BlogEntryLong :blog="blog" :key="blogId" />
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    import BlogEntryLong from "@/components/BlogEntryLong.vue";
    import { mapActions } from "vuex";
    import { mapState } from "vuex";

    export default {
      name: "BlogEntry",
      components: {
        BlogEntryLong,
      },
      data() {
        return {
          blogId: this.$route.params.blogId,
        };
      },
      methods: {
        ...mapActions(["fetchIndividualBlog"]),
      },

      computed: {
        ...mapState(["blog"]),
      },
    };
    </script>

    <style scoped></style>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue.js - update router view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60057473/vue-js-update-router-view)

Comment: This was one of the solutions I tried and it also did not work.  My App.vue's template looks like this while trying to key router-view to the fullPath key:

`<template>
  <div id="app">
    <TopNav></TopNav>
    <router-view :key="$route.fullPath" />
  </div>
</template>`

This didn't work however, so removing the key to full path.  For others, here is the link to documentation on $route properties: [https://router.vuejs.org/api/#route-object-properties]

Thanks for the note regardless.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion: The router file is now in the question above.  However, I'm not as interested in including the component - trying to keep this clutter-free ... unless there's something specific you suspect there?

Comment: I've updated my question to be more clear hopefully: My project 'works' with my workaround.  

Basically, I'm asking if I'm 'missing something' from what I think should be a standard - and common - use case for routing.  If it's an SPA thing from an architectural perspective that's fine.  Or if there's some Vue option that I'm unaware of, that's fine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On RouterView page

```
<template>
    <div>
        <NavBar @update="key=Math.random()" />
        <RouterView :key=key />
    </div>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
const key = ref(0);
</script>
```

On your NavBar

```
<template>
    <div>
        <router-link @click="emits('update')">Foo</router-link>
    </div>
    <div>
        <router-link @click="emits('update')">Bar</router-link>
    </div>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
const emits = defineEmits(['update']);
</script>
```

If you're clicking on the same link, it will refresh the router-view component.
However, if you're clicking on a different link, it will refresh the component before you switch a page

Answer (score 0):

On the App.vue, add the dynamic :key to the router-view

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <TopNav></TopNav>
    <router-view :key="$route.fullPath" />
  </div>
</template>
```