# Why routing to same component but different parameters does not work in Vue.js using vue-router?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a code in my Vue.js app where I'm going to load different data on same component but different parameters. I'm using vue-router. The route changes but the component does not reload. The component only changes if I go to a different route. I added different keys on each list-item but it does not change anything.

Template :

```
<v-list two-line>
                <v-list-item-group active-class="">
                    <template v-for="(item, index) in $store.getters.notifications.data">
                        <v-list-item :key="item.id" @click="redirectPage(item)">
                            <template>
                                <v-list-item-content>
                                    <v-list-item-title
                                        v-text="item.data.data.employee.full_name"
                                    ></v-list-item-title>

                                    <v-list-item-subtitle
                                        class="text--primary"
                                        v-text="item.data.data.description"
                                    ></v-list-item-subtitle>

                                    <v-list-item-subtitle
                                        v-text="mixin_getHumanDate(item.created_at)"
                                    ></v-list-item-subtitle>
                                </v-list-item-content>
                            </template>
                        </v-list-item>

                        <v-divider
                            v-if="index < items.length - 1"
                            :key="index"
                        ></v-divider>
                    </template>
                </v-list-item-group>
            </v-list>
```

Method:

```
methods: {
        redirectPage(item) {

            let _this = this;

            axios
                .put(`/api/notifications/${item.id}?action=${'read'}&type=${'single'}`)
                .then(response => {
                    _this.$store.dispatch("AUTH_NOTIFICATIONS");

                    _this.$router.push(`/admin/${item.data.data.model}/${item.data.data.id}`);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                    console.log(error.response);
                });
        },
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue.js - update router view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60058175/2185093)