# Vue - force update on new id in URL

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

In my Vue2 app, I am using the id parameter on a component that occupies the main view, e.g.
`http://localhost:8080/#/basereports/watercombochart/129`

indicates that the chart with id settings corresponding to 129 is loaded.

This all works great except that if I get the same URL with only the id changed, I have to manually refresh in order to get it to reload.  Vue is not detecting a change.

I use keys all the time to force *child* components to refresh, but the main view components are not children, so I'm not sure how to re-invoke the component in order to force an update.

What is a good way to trigger update of a non-child component when the id on the URL changes?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60058175/2185093

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to [Dan's link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60058175/2185093) in his comment above, it was the clue I needed. I was able to get my body component to re-render even if only the URL parameter changed.  The code below injects that main body component into the view area of my SPA and attaches the footer component below it:

```
<template>
  <v-main>
    <router-view :key="$route.fullPath" />
    <c-v-footer />
  </v-main>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'CVView',
    components: {
      CVFooter: () => import('./CVFooter'),
    },
  }
</script>
```

My original code did not include the :key=$route.fullPath prop, and the main body component would not re-render if only the URL parameter changed.

Comment: One way to view this is that the above component is a child component of the  router component.  Not sure if that is accurate but it mostly fits the facts.  If so, then this is just the same re-rendering technique I use to manage child forms that need to be re-initialized when invoked from a parent.